# Playbooks that needs to be tweaked depending on the targeted environment

Tags: ansible

In our company we're using ansible to target different environments, about 10 on the development and integration side, and 3 on the production side. Those environments have some differences in terms of the number of resources dedicated. For example let say in production we have a standalone server or vm dedicated to run the jvm, another one for dB... And in certain other environments those applications share the same server or vm. The problem is that some playbooks needs to be tweaked in order to target such an environment, so how could we do to make it as generic and transparent as possible?

Thanks for your advices

Comment: This is really a broad question and there could be multiple correct answers depending on a lot of parameters... What I usually do is seperate those environment in different inventories holding the same groups. You can then have different machines for the `jvm` and `db` group in `inventory/prod` and use the same machine name in `inventory/dev1`. Ellaborating on this would require that you give us a little more precision on the kind of tweeks you need to have in your playbooks.

Answer (score 0):

what you want to achieve is putting good hosts in good groups.
if you're familiar with ansible-inventory --graph, here is what you want to achieve:

```
@all:
  |--@dev:
  |    |--devel1.domain.org
  |    |--devel2.domain.org
  |--@db:
  |    |--db1.domain.org
  |    |--db2.domain.org
  |    |--dbprod1.domain.org
  |    |--appprod2.domain.org
  |--@app:
  |    |--app1.domain.org
  |    |--app2.domain.org
  |    |--appprod1.domain.org
  |    |--appprod2.domain.org
  |--@dev1:
  |    |--devel1.domain.org
  |    |--db1.domain.org
  |    |--app1.domain.org
  |--@dev2:
  |    |--devel2.domain.org
  |    |--db2.domain.org
  |    |--app2.domain.org
  |--@prod:
  |    |--@prod1:
  |    |    |--dbprod1.domain.org
  |    |    |--appprod1.domain.org
  |    |--@prod2:
  |    |    |--appprod2.domain.org
```

here the host `appprod2.domain.org` will inherit from group_vars of app,db, prod,prod2